# Regarding Partiton of hard Disc?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I bought Lenovo z500 with a 1 TB harddrive.

In that harddrive I have two partitions other than the C-drive, but there is 400 GB left in the entire harddrive.

I can't figure out how to include it to make use of the space as e.g. an extra partiton. Please advise about this.

Thanks and Regards,
Sharath

Comment: What tools have you tried using?

Comment: There are a lot of differnet tools for that out there e.g partition magic. You also can look for free tools to accomplish your task. I also would recomend to backup you system beore using any tool. This is a task you could easy mess up your system.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without having to install additional software, would be to use [the Disk Management-tool](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm) in Windows (I assume you use Windows from the naming of the drive).

Then un-partitioned space can be included in an existing partition, if the un-partitioned space is directly to the right if the partition you want to expand to this area and if the file systems is NTFS (I am unsure whether e.g. FAT32/exFat can do the same).

To do this, right click the partition you want to expand and click "Expand".

You can also format is as a new, individual partition by right clicking on the un-partitioned area and press "Format".

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 partitions other than your C: drive that means you have a total of 4 partitions (1 System Partition). Assuming these are [primary partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning), you cannot create more than 4 primary partitions.
To achieve this task you need to create an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition) (or Logical Partition). Within this extended partition you can create as many partition as you want.

I suggest you :

1. Use any partition manager :

   > - [Minitool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://partitionwizard.com/download.html)
   > - [EaseUS Partition Master Home Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm)
   > - [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/)
   > - [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)
   > - [Paragon Partition Manager](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/)
2. A total of 4 Primary partition can reside on Hard Disk. So you need to convert one of your partition to Extended Partition **[Please Make Backup of your data before this operation!!!]**
3. Now extend this partition so that it occupies remaining 400 GB. Now you can create as many partition as you want within this partition.

**Important!! Please make backup of your data before performing any
partition activity**

Hope this helps. (: